# Create multiple equal height columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one page based on 5 sections with two 50% columns each. 
Now I'm trying to apply the height of the independent column to the dependent column using following jQuery code. The problem is that it only gets the height of the column in the first section and applies this height to all other dependent columns. How can I achieve that it differentiates between sections?

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  jQuery('.dependent_div').css({
    'min-height': jQuery('.independent_div').innerHeight()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Please add markup</div>
```

Comment: What is your markup?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. But I think specifically in your code, you’re wanting to iterate through each ‘.dependent_div’. For that try .each()